# jQuery scale after page load

Tags: jquery, scale

I am trying to animate 2 `div`s that scale up (one after the other) after the page loads.

My goal is for `div 1` to appear by scaling in (from the center of the `div`) after a delay, then **`div 2`** to *scale in* after a slightly longer delay.

As an extra, I am also trying for each div to scale slightly on hover and back to normal after mouse out.

---

**EDIT:** I have something going here http://jsfiddle.net/uwybR/7/ but hover effect is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the code you got, do a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please also include the code of what you've tried.

Comment: I got most of it except the hover effect: http://jsfiddle.net/uwybR/7/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably what you want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').animate({
        width:'new width',
        height:'new height'
    },500, function(){
        $('#div2').animate({
            width:'new width',
            height:'new height'
        }, 500)
    })
})
```

The second div will animate AFTER the first has finished. If you want them to run almost simultaneously you're going to have to use `setTimeout()`.

For your hover check out [the hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Take a look at this. Hover was giving me some trouble and there still seems to be a little delay before it scales, but this is as close as I can get it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwybR/16/)

Comment: Ah, thats a good approach, but going this way, how do I get the content inside to scale and get the div to scale from the center?

Comment: Well if the content is pure CSS with it's own styles, that's not really feasible. Instead of .animate, you can try .addClass('scaleClass') and in your CSS do a CSS3 2D transform scale, but if you want everything inside to scale with the parent, I would use an image in the div's background set to 'cover'